# How to connect different Regional S3 Bucket from a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Boot application that has a POST end-point that accepts 2 types of files.  Based on the file category, I need to write them to S3 buckets which are in different regions. Example: Category 1 file should be written to Frankfurt (eu-central-1) and Category 2 file should be written to Ohio (us-east-2) S3 buckets. Spring boot accepts a static region (cloud.aws.region.static=eu-central-1) through property configuration and the connection is established when starting the Spring boot so the AmazoneS3 Client Bean is already created with a connection to Frankfurt itself.

I need to containerize this entire setup and deploy it in a K8 Pod.

What is the recommendation for establishing connections and writing objects to different regional buckets? How do I need to implement this? Looking for a dynamic region finding solution rather statically created Bean per region.

Below is a working piece of code that connects to Frankfurt bucket and PUT the object.

```
@Service
public class S3Service {

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 amazonS3Client;
    
    public void putObject(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        
        ObjectMetadata objectMetaData = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetaData.setContentType(multipartFile.getContentType());
        objectMetaData.setContentLength(multipartFile.getSize());

        try {
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("example-bucket", multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), multipartFile.getInputStream(), objectMetaData);
            this.amazonS3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
            /* Handle Exception */
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated Code (20/08/2021)**

```
@Component
public class AmazoneS3ConnectionFactory {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmazoneS3ConnectionFactory.class);
    
    @Value("${example.aws.s3.regions}")
    private String[] regions;
    
    @Autowired
    private DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private AWSCredentialsProvider credentialProvider;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        
        for(String region: this.regions) {
            
            String amazonS3BeanName = region + "_" + "amazonS3";
            
            if (!this.beanFactory.containsBean(amazonS3BeanName)) {
                
                AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                        .withCredentials(this.credentialProvider).withRegion(region).withChunkedEncodingDisabled(true);
                AmazonS3 awsS3 = builder.build();
                this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(amazonS3BeanName, awsS3);
                
                LOGGER.info("Bean " + amazonS3BeanName + " - Not exist. Created a bean and registered the same");
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns {@link AmazonS3} for a region. Uses the default {@link AWSCredentialsProvider}
     */
    public AmazonS3 getConnection(String region) {
        
        String amazonS3BeanName = region + "_" + "amazonS3";
        return (AmazonS3Client)this.beanFactory.getBean(amazonS3BeanName, AmazonS3.class);
    }
}
```

My Service layer will call the "getConnection()" and get the AmazonS3 Object to operate on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option that I am aware is to create different `S3Client` with [S3ClientBuilder](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3ClientBuilder.html), one for each different region. You would need to register them as Spring Beans with different names so that you can later autowire them.

---

**Update (19/08/2021)**

The following should work (sorry for the Kotlin code but it is faster to write):

Class that may contain your configuration for each region.

```
class AmazonS3Properties(val accessKeyId: String,
                     val secretAccessKey: String,
                     val region: String,
                     val bucket: String)
```

Configuration for S3 that will create 2 S3Clients and stored the buckets for each region (later needed).

```
@Configuration
class AmazonS3Configuration(private val s3Properties: Map<String, AmazonS3Properties>) {

  lateinit var buckets: Map<String, String>

  @PostConstruct
  fun init() {
    buckets = s3Properties.mapValues { it.bucket }
  }

  @Bean(name = "regionA")
  fun regionA(): S3Client {
    val regionAProperties = s3Properties["region-a"]
    val awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(regionAProperties.accessKeyId, regionAProperties.secretAccessKey)
    return S3Client.builder().region(Region.of(regionAProperties.region)).credentialsProvider { awsCredentials }.build()
  }

  @Bean(name = "regionB")
  fun regionB(): S3Client {
    val regionBProperties = s3Properties["region-b"]
    val awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(regionBProperties.accessKeyId, regionBProperties.secretAccessKey)
    return S3Client.builder().region(Region.of(regionBProperties.region)).credentialsProvider { awsCredentials }.build()
  }
}
```

Service that will target one of the regions (Region A)

```
@Service
class RegionAS3Service(private val amazonS3Configuration: AmazonS3Configuration,
                       @field:Qualifier("regionA") private val amazonS3Client: S3Client) {

  fun save(region: String, byteArrayOutputStream: ByteArrayOutputStream) {
      val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())
      val contentLength = byteArrayOutputStream.size().toLong()

      amazonS3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(amazonS3Configuration.buckets[region]).key("whatever-key").build(), RequestBody.fromInputStream(inputStream, contentLength))
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done that but throwing error 1st time while PutObject is called on the S3Client Object. `public AmazonS3 getConnection(AWSCredentialsProvider credProvider, String region) {
  
  String amazonS3BeanName = region + "_" + "amazonS3";

  if (!this.beanFactory.containsBean(amazonS3BeanName)) {
   
   AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = this.createS3Connection(credProvider, region);
   AmazonS3 awsS3 = builder.build();
   this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(amazonS3BeanName, awsS3);
  } 
  
  return (AmazonS3Client)this.beanFactory.getBean(amazonS3BeanName, AmazonS3.class);
 }`

Comment: 'private AmazonS3ClientBuilder createS3Connection(AWSCredentialsProvider credProvider, String region) {
  
  return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
    .withCredentials(credentialProvider).withRegion(region).withChunkedEncodingDisabled(true);
 }'

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rest of the code from beginning `@Component
public class AmazoneS3ConnectionFactory {

 @Autowired
 private DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
 
 @Autowired
 private AWSCredentialsProvider credentialProvider;
 
 public AmazonS3 getConnection(String region) {
  
  return this.getConnection(this.credentialProvider, region);
 }`

Comment: I am able to store objects using this implementation but throwing the below error: 'com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
 at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.951.jar:na] ............................... Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
 at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]`

Comment: Can you please add this to the original question? It is very difficult to read it as comments.

Comment: @user3792889 I've updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: So sorry for including the code in the comment. It was almost the same as your code only thing was registering the beans after creation in the spring bean factory when a request comes in the controller. Now I have improved the implementation based on your code example. Please see above & suggest me if anything.

Comment: It is different from what I've suggested but it looks good to me and maybe it even fits better your use case.